# Sequence of data received in server in socket is inverted

Tags: c++, sockets

I have 1 server handle multiple clients connect to it by using epoll in edge-triggering mode

Each message have timestamp, specify the time that is sent from client.

The problem I face is:

The order of message in a list on server is mixed-up.
For example: 
Message A with timestamp 1 from client X should be arrive before Message B with timestamp 2 from client Y, but the server receive message B before Message A

How can I ensure the order of data between multiple client connected to server through socket (TCP/UDS)

Comment: Sort them by timestamp in your code. There's no guarantee that data sent on different independent connections would arrive in any particular order - just like there's no guarantee that a letter sent earlier by boat would arrive before a letter sent later, but by airmail.

Comment: Also note that the timestamps could be misleading, unless all client-systems are synchronized to the same clock.